# Is there some mini-plugs for this connector?

Tags: connector, pins

I have this connector pictured below. For now I've been soldering my wires directly into these pins. But for some occasions it would be nice to have removable wires. Does some sort of mini pin connectors exist that can be attached onto these?

[image]

Comment: they look intended for crimp termination to me.  what is the diameter of the hole.

Comment: Those look like solder terminals to me, permanently moulded into the connector body. There might be a crimp terminal version of the connector, with removable pins but it's not the one pictured. What connector model is it? Does the manufacturer list a crimp version in their catalogues?

Comment: Yep, solder those to wires that have an actual unpluggable connector on them.

Comment: Here is the product https://www.elfadistrelec.no/no/kabelkontakt-sv-pinners-5a-250v-poler-plugg-lumberg-connect-gmbh-sv-40/p/14402926 and here is the documentation https://www.elfadistrelec.no/Web/Downloads/_t/ds/sfv_sgv-series_eng_fre_ger_tds.pdf
I see now that the documentation specifies "solder terminals".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some mini-plugs for this connector?

No. Those are solder cups. You place a stripped wire in a cup and solder it.

Comment: The documentation confirms your answer: https://www.elfadistrelec.no/Web/Downloads/_t/ds/sfv_sgv-series_eng_fre_ger_tds.pdf :)